# Non duplicate records with max date query on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, max

Hello i have a problem with a simple query. I need to see the max date of some articles in two direfent sites.

This is my actual query:

```
SELECT a.aa_codart, MAX(t.tr_fechafac), t.tr_tipo
FROM ARTALM a, traspaso t
WHERE t.tr_codart = a.aa_codart
and t.tr_tipomov > 1
and a.aa_codalm = '1'
and (t.tr_tipo >= 1 and t.tr_tipo <=2)
group by a.aa_codart, t.tr_tipo;
```

And the result:

```
01..FRB10X80    30/11/07    2
01..FRB10X80    08/03/01    1
01.32122RS      05/02/16    1
01.32122RS      02/07/10    2
01.33052Z       21/09/15    1
01.60042Z       24/02/16    2
```

I want, for example in the two first rows, see only one row, like this:

```
01..FRB10X80    30/11/07    2
01.32122RS      05/02/16    1
01.33052Z       21/09/15    1
01.60042Z       24/02/16    2
```

Taking the max date

Thanks

Comment: looking at your query it is returning the correct results as AA000183200100091D and AA000185200100091D are different and 
since you are grouping by aa_codart the result will be as you have it.

Comment: AA000183... AA000185...  I don't see how you determine those values should be combined.  The result your getting seems correct for the reasons @KamranFarzami pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for an analytical query. This query shows how the `ROW_NUMBER()` function will assign the value `1` to the row with the article's most recent date. Give it a try first to help understand the final query, coming up next:

```
SELECT
  a.aa_codart,
  t.tr_fechafac,
  t.tr_tipo,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.aa_codart ORDER BY t.tr_fechafac DESC) as rnk
FROM artalm a
INNER JOIN trapaso t ON a.aa_codart = t.tr_codart
WHERE t.tr_tipomov > 1
  AND a.aa_codalm = '1'
  AND t.tr_tipo BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

You can't apply the `WHERE` clause to the `rnk` column because the column is calculated *after* the `WHERE` clause. You can get around this using a nested query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    a.aa_codart,
    t.tr_fechafac,
    t.tr_tipo,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.aa_codart ORDER BY t.tr_fechafac DESC) as rnk
  FROM artalm a
  INNER JOIN trapaso t ON a.aa_codart = t.tr_codart
  WHERE t.tr_tipomov > 1
    AND a.aa_codalm = '1'
    AND t.tr_tipo BETWEEN 1 AND 2
) WHERE rnk = 1;
```

I apologize in advance for any column names I may have retyped badly. The Oracle syntax should be fine; the column names maybe not so much :)

Comment: The second query is the correct, but when i execute the result is more than 100.000 and the correct will be like 20.000 or less. Where will be the problem?

Comment: Without knowing more about your data it's really hard to tell. Could you give me an example of a result row you got that should be in the results, plus a row that shouldn't?

Comment: AA_CODART           TR_FECHAFAC       TR_TIPO       RNK

AA00012520110 28/01/98                    2                1

Srry about format, i dont know how to put it right

Comment: No problem with the format. Was that one that *should* have been in the result, or one that *shouldn't* have?

Comment: No problem Ed, i think i did a parch with excel hehe, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look at row_number() (then just pick the ones where it is one) something like this.

```
WITH t
     AS (SELECT 'A' aa_codart,
                TO_DATE ('17/05/00', 'dd/mm/yy') mydt,
                1 tr_tipo
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'A', TO_DATE ('12/04/00', 'dd/mm/yy'), 2 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'B', TO_DATE ('30/06/98', 'dd/mm/yy'), 2 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'C', TO_DATE ('30/06/98 ', 'dd/mm/yy'), 2 FROM DUAL),
     t2
     AS (SELECT aa_codart,
                mydt,
                tr_tipo,
                ROW_NUMBER ()
                   OVER (PARTITION BY aa_codart ORDER BY mydt DESC)
                   rn
           FROM t)
SELECT *
  FROM t2
 WHERE rn = 1
```